# How to get rid of "ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive" powershell error

Tags: powershell

```
  $FX_USER=$args[0]
  $FX_PWD=$args[1]
  $FX_JOBID=$args[2]
  $REGION=$args[3]
  $TAGS=$args[4]
  $SUITES=$args[5]
  $CATEGORIES=$args[6]
  $FX_HOST=$args[7]      

  $taskStatus="WAITING"
  Write-Host "taskStatus = " $taskStatus


 while ( ("$taskStatus" -eq "WAITING") -or ("$taskStatus" -eq "PROCESSING") ) 
           { 
    sleep 5
     Write-Host "Checking Status...."

             $passPercent=$(curl -k --header "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" -X GET -u ""${FX_USER}":"${FX_PWD}"" ""${FX_HOST}"/api/v1/runs/${runId}" | jq -r '."data"|.ciCdStatus')


              $array =  $passPercent  | ConvertFrom-Json 

        $taskStatus="${array[0]}"
             Write-Host "task-status= $taskStatus"
             Write-Host "Status =" "${array[0]}" " Success Percent =" "${array[1]}"  " Total Tests =" "${array[2]}" " Time Taken =" "${array[4]}" " Run =" "${array[5]}"
```

when i run this code of powershell i got following error from console output.

ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: WAITING.
At C:\Users\Administrator\test.ps1:57 char:45
+                   $array =  $passPercent  | ConvertFrom-Json
+                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

Status =   Success Percent =   Total Tests =   Time Taken =   Run =

I am supposed to get some values either in string or interger after = sign in above fields like Status= Completed, 
Can anyone help me out its urgent.
Thanks

Comment: nvm, it appears you’re using `jq` to deal with the JSON. So before using `ConvertFrom-Json` you should check if `$passPercent` even contains JSON.

Comment: this is what is store in passPercent after curl                                                                  passPercent=WAITING:0.0:0:0:null:null:38:/#/app/projects/8a80808a69c899f10169c8a0d0610005/jobs/8a80808a69c899f10169c8a0da020079/runs/8a8080f169d28d430169d35e399401f8:Bugs Logged = 0 Bugs Reopened = 0 Bugs Closed = 0 Total Bugs = 0